# Serious vulnerability in 3.5.0 on Android - cli issue when running build with cordova 3.6.3

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3

Since there is a serious vulnerability in the cordova versions 3.5.0 and lower.

When I've updated cordova to 3.6.3

```
npm uninstall cordova -g
npm install cordova - g
cordova -v
3.6.3-0.2.13
```

I am also on phonegap version 3.5.0-0.21.18.

The build fails on cli saying that my Android SDK is missing a build.template for the platform tools. Here is what I have done done;

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
phonegap build android

[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...

C:\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
throw e;
^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Android SDK\sdk\platform-tools\tools    \lib\build.template'
```

I have tired updating the SDK platform tools but this issue is still happening any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've fixed this issue by doing the following;

```
cordova platform rm android
phonegap build android
```

When I've removed the platform from my app and then tell phonegap to build it would seem that it downloads the latest cordova from the phonegap server rather than cordova's. It therefore installs cordova 3.5.1 rather than cordova 3.6.3 which by passes the vulnerabilty issue and resolves phonegap command line from not building.

I hope that helps anyone else who may have encountered this problem, seems odd that there is no information on phonegap's website about this.

Answer (score 6):

In my Windows OS case, I've added semicolon to the value of ANDROID_HOME Environment variable and somehow it worked.(with cordova 3.6.3-0.2.13)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but in linux, not windows.

Check your Environment variables in particular:
ANDROID_HOME

and remove the tail spaces

Comment: I have got it set to C:\Android SDK\sdk\ and I've tried to alter it to C:\Android SDK\sdk\platform-tools\ If I downgrade cordova to 3.4.0 and add the platform, followed by a build seems to work. But this isn't really helpful because that version still contains the vulnerability. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding " to the beggining and the end of `ANDROID_HOME` variable value( In my case: **D:\Android Studio Windows\sdk\tools**, which became **"D:\Android Studio Windows\sdk\tools"**) and it worked. For some reason, with blankspaces, it has some troubles.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed ANDROID_HOME from c:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\ to c:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk and it worked. I also re-open a new CMD to make sure I'm using the new updated variable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had multiple versions on cordova installed (3.6 and 4.0)
So I now run both plafotm add and build commands from full path for cordova

```
/usr/local/bin/cordova platform add android
/usr/local/bin/cordova build android
```